# Azure functions keep on running, inserting 10x values in Database

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I have built a pipeline with Stream Analytics data triggering Azure Functions.

There are 5000 values merged in a single data. I wrote a simple python program in the Function to validate the data, parse the bulk data, and save it in Cosmos DB as an individual document. But the problem is, my functions don't stop. After 30 minutes I can see that my function generated an error saying timed out. And in these 30 minutes, I can see more than 300k values in my database which are duplicating themselves. I thought this problem is with my code (for loop) and I tried running it locally, and everything works. I am not sure why this is the problem. In the whole code, the only statement, I am unable to understand is in **container.upsert** line.

This is my code:

```
import logging
import azure.functions as func
import hashlib as h
from azure.cosmos import CosmosClient
import random, string

def generateRandomID(length):
    # choose from all lowercase letter
    letters = string.ascii_lowercase
    result_str = ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(length))
    return result_str


URL = dburl
KEY = dbkey
client = CosmosClient(URL, credential=KEY)

DATABASE_NAME = dbname
database = client.get_database_client(DATABASE_NAME)
CONTAINER_NAME = containername 
container = database.get_container_client(CONTAINER_NAME)


def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    req_body = req.get_json()

    try:
        #Level 1
        rawMsg = req_body[0]
        filteredMsg = rawMsg['message']
        metaData = rawMsg['metaData']
        logging.info(metaData)

        encodeMD5 = filteredMsg.encode('utf-8')
        generateMD5 = h.md5(encodeMD5).hexdigest()

        parsingMetaData = metaData.split(',')
        parsingMD5Hex =  parsingMetaData[3]
        splitingHex = parsingMD5Hex.split(':')
        parsingMD5Value = splitingHex[1]

    except:
        logging.info("Failed to parse the Data and Generate MD5 Checksums. Error at the level 1")


    finally:
        logging.info("Execution Successful | First level Completed ")
        #return func.HttpResponse(f"OK")


    try:
        #Level 2:
        if generateMD5 == parsingMD5Value:
        #parsing the ecg values
            logging.info('MD5 Checksums matched!')
            splitValues = filteredMsg.split(',')
            for eachValue in range(len(splitValues)):
                ecgRawData = splitValues[eachValue]
                divideEachValue = ecgRawData.split(':')
                timeData = divideEachValue[0]
                ecgData = divideEachValue[1]
                container.upsert_item({ 'id': generateRandomID(10), 'time': timeData, 'ecgData': ecgData})

        elif generateMD5 != parsingMD5Hex:
            logging.info('The MD5s did not matched and couldnt execute the code properly')
            logging.info(generateMD5)

        else:
            logging.info('Something is going wrong. Please check.')

    except:
        logging.info("Failed to parse ECG Values into the DB Container. Error ar the level 2")

    finally:
        logging.info("Execution Successful | Second level complete ")
        #return func.HttpResponse(f"OK")
        

    # Return a 200 status
    return func.HttpResponse(f"OK")
```

A test I performed:
Commented the **for loop** block and deployed the Function, **it executes normally without any error.**

Please let me know how I can address this issue and also if there is a wrong way of code practice.

Comment: Did you add a log line inside the `for` loop? If you see that log line continuously printing, then the problem is the input (splitValues) and the logic generating the `range(len(splitValues))`. The Cosmos SDKs wouldn't automatically generate hundreds of items, most commonly it's the logic that is calling the operation (upsert_item) that might have some flaw.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution! (I am the OP)

In my resource group, an App service plan is enabled for a Web application. So, when creating an Azure Function, it doesn't let me deploy it in the Serverless option. So, I deployed with the same app service plan used for Web applications. And while testing, the function completely works except for the **container.upsert** line. When I add this line, it fails to stop and creates 10x values in the database until it gets stopped by a timeout error beyond 30 minutes.

I tried creating an App Service plan dedicated to this Function. But the issue is still the same.

And while testing with 100s of corner case scenarios, I found out that my function runs perfectly when I deploy it in the other resource group. The only catch is, I have opted for the Serverless option while deploying the Functions.

(If you are using an App service plan in your Azure Resource Group, you cannot deploy Azure Functions with a Serverless option. It shows the deployment is not proper. You need to create a dedicated app service plan for that function or you should use the existing App service plan)

As per my research, when dealing with bulk data and inserting those data into the database, the usual app service plan doesn't work. The App Service Plan should be large enough to sustain the load. Or you should choose the Serverless option while deploying the Function, as the compute is totally managed by Azure.

Hope this helps.